# Mongoose dot notation $inc update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document as follows:

```
{
  "_id" : "1",

  "myplaylists" : [{
      "_id" : "2",
      "name" : "Playlist_0",
      "likes" : 712,
      "views" : 7110
    }],
  "name" : "First name, Last name"
}
```

and I want to do an update and increment "myplaylists.likes"

what I did is:

```
User.update( {'myplaylists._id': 2}, {$inc: { 'myplaylists.likes': 1 }}
```

but it doesn't seem to work because of the dot notation in the $inc

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) `$` to identify the matched array element to update:

```
User.update( {'myplaylists._id': 2}, {$inc: { 'myplaylists.$.likes': 1 }}
```